# Deleting one of a collection on parent update

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring

I am trying to delete (or create) a models associated objects when it is updated. Each bar has several taps. When you create a bar, these tap objects are created, and you can update that number and additional taps will be created or deleted as necessary.

Originally I just wanted to use `pop` like this:

```
        $taps=$bar->taps;
        if ( $taps_old < $taps_new){
            for ($i = $taps_old; $i < $taps_new; $i++) {
                $tap = Growlertap::create(['growlerstation_id' => $id]);
            }
        }
        elseif ($taps_old > $taps_new) {
            for ($i = $taps_new; $i < $taps_old; $i++) {
                $taps->pop();
            }
```

which doesn't work but doesn't give me an error. I know the if statement is working fine because the code below works:

```
        elseif ($taps_old > $taps_new) {
            for ($i = $taps_new; $i < $taps_old; $i++) {
                Beertap::where('bar_id', '=', $id)->first()->delete();
            }
        }
```

This seems to not be the simplest way to write this. Is there a better way to write this?

By the way, for those wondering, this is in my update function in my controller.

Comment: @J.T.Grimes quote: "but doesn't give me an error"

Comment: @hodale oops - I clearly need to work on my reading skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop()` will remove the last item in your local collection, but it won't persist that change to the database.

Assuming it's a `Beertap` object, something like this should work:

Warning: untested code

```
    ...
    elseif ($taps_old > $taps_new) {
        for ($i = $taps_new; $i < $taps_old; $i++) {
            $delete_me = $taps->pop();
            $delete_me->delete();
        }
    }
```

or more succinctly: `$taps->pop()->delete();`

Answer (score 1):

<s>This should work</s> Unfortunately this doesn't work because the DELETE statement doesn't support offsets.

```
Beertap::where('bar_id')->skip($taps_new)->delete();
```

So it skips as many taps as you want to keep and deletes the rest. You might want to use `orderBy` if it matters which rows get deleted.

### Update

This should totally work now. First get all id's to delete from the collection and then delete them with *one query*

```
$idsToDelete = $taps->slice($taps_new)->modelKeys();
Beertap::destroy($idsToDelete);
```

### Update 2

You can optimize the creation process as well (so that it's done in a single query)

```
$data = [];
for ($i = $taps_old; $i < $taps_new; $i++) {
    $data[] = ['growlerstation_id' => $id];
}
Beertap::insert($data);
```

*Note* that you will loose the Eloquent features like automatic timestamps and model events when choosing to use `insert()`.

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it to work quite right. It deletes the entire collection instead of the excess. I tried adding get() after the skip: `Beertap::where('bar_id')->skip($taps_new)->get()->delete();` and that threw this error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 20' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `growlertaps` where `growlerstation_id` = 1 offset 20)`

Comment: Cool that works! Now I don't need the for loop. Now I just need to figure out how to create a batch all at once.